# Set Up Visual Studio 2012 for Enterprise Portal Development

Tags: visual-studio-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there any way to get VS2012 set up for Enterprise Portal developing?

I already installed the EP Dev Kit for VS2010 and am able to build and deploy EP UserControls, but how to achieve this in VS2012?

[MSDN says you have to use VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc572801.aspx)

Have I overseen something? Anybody knows about a workaround or something?

The complete solution and all referenced projects are built in VS2012 so it would be nice if there wasn't any need to have VS2010 involved for a single UserControl for AX.

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, MSDN says:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 is required to create or modify User
>   Controls for Enterprise Portal

The visual studio components for AX don't work with VS2012 so you are stuck with VS2010. I don't know of any way to make it work but even if it was a workaround I would **not** recommend it since Microsoft says otherwise. You will not get support and you wouldn't be sure if any problems you face are due to using VS2012.

From that same page, these are the ones that are supported:

> Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Visual Studio 2010 Premium, and
>   Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

It's not convenient but not a problem since you can run VS2010 and VS2012 side by side.

Comment: Yes, you can run them side-by-side, but it's not as nice as it could be since all other parts of the project are done in VS2012!